# Как установить индикатор (ProgressDialog) на операцию

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Есть такой код:

```
public void delete(File f){
    if(!f.exists()){
        return;
    }
    if(f.isDirectory()){
        for(File d : f.listFiles()){
            delete(d);
        }
        f.delete();
    }else{
        f.delete();
    }
}
```

Это метод для удаления файла, или файлов из выбраной директории..
Если удалять большой файл, или много  файлов, происходит подвисание...
Я хочу установить в этот код `ProgressDialog` для того чтоб при длительной операции удаления, пользователь не думал, что приложение зависло, НО как это сделать я незнаю...
Подскажите (приведите пример редактирования моего кода) для достижения заданой цели..

Comment: Вынесите "затратную" операцию в  AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Если просто добавить `ProgressDialog` в существующий код, то он будет также подвисать как и остальной UI. Поэтому тяжёлую операцию удаления нужно поместить в background поток. Например с помощью [`AsyncTask`](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html):

```
class DeleteFileTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Заголовок", "Сообщение");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(File... params) {
        File f = params[0];

        delete(f);  // Вызов вашей текущей функции

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Запускать нужно так:

```
new DeleteFileTask().execute(someFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Объявите progressDialog в вашем классе:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Затем в методе инициализуруйте его таким способом:

```
    public void delete(File f){
        if(!f.exists()){
            return;
        }
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(),"Удаление","Подождите, пожалуйста...",false,false);
            for(File d : f.listFiles()){
                delete(d);
            }
            f.delete();
        }else{
            f.delete();
        }
            progressDialog.dismiss();  // прячем progressDialog тут, или можно после вызова метода
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В xml добавляем прогресс с выключенным режимом

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:visibility="invisible"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminate="false"
android:max="100"
android:progress="5" />
```

Когда надо делаем прогресс бар видимым

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

У прогресс бара есть такие методы:

```
setProgress() — устанавливает заданное значение индикатора прогресса;
getProgress() — возвращает текущее значение индикатора прогресса;
incrementProgressBy() — устанавливает величину дискретизации приращения значения индикатора;
```

Тяжелые операции необходимо выносить в другой поток, тут отдельная тема. Начиная от AsyncTask (но можно получить утечку памяти) - заканчивая RxJava.